# Windows Phone 8 - Javascript : back button

Tags: javascript, html, windows-phone-8, back-button

I need to handle the back button in HTML 5 - Javascript application for Windows Phone 8. I found a lot of solutions in C# but no one in Javascript.
Does anybody know how to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

//Hardware back button could be handle using this.

```
 var hardwareButtons = Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons;
    hardwareButtons.addEventListener("backpressed", function (e) {
      e.handled = true; //handle back button event(won't close the app).
      history.back(); //go back to history
    });
```

Comment: I've been looking everywhere for a solution for this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code that work on windows phone 7 & 8

```
//WPback button handler methods
$(document).ready(function()
{
document.addEventListener("deviceready", setOverrideBackbutton, false);
});

function setOverrideBackbutton()
{
document.addEventListener("backbutton", backButtonTap, true);
}

/**
 * Callback after a backbutton tap on windows platforms.
 * Do nothing.
 */
function backButtonTap()
{
//Do not remove
}
```

Comment: I try this, but when I click on the back button, that's still quit the application. I just need to put this code in my application right ?

Comment: You have to put this code into your js file and call it a the beginning

Comment: Thanks a lot @dpfauwadel, you just saved my day. Note for other user : you can code  your actions in backButtonTap() :D

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PhoneGap, have a look at http://www.risingj.com/archives/493

Comment: Sorry I don't use PhoneGap.