# Cordova for windows phone 8.1 back button handle

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, cordova, windows-phone-8.1

Sorry my English.

I use Visual Studio 2015 and write hybrid app for WP8.1 using cordova.
I use this code:

```js
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var app;

    document.addEventListener( 'deviceready', onDeviceReady.bind( this ), false );

   

    function onDeviceReady() {
        // Handle the Cordova pause and resume events
        document.addEventListener( 'pause', onPause.bind( this ), false );
        document.addEventListener('resume', onResume.bind(this), false);        
        document.addEventListener('backbutton', back.bind(this), false);
        
        console.log("test");
        
        // TODO: Cordova has been loaded. Perform any initialization that requires Cordova here.


        ///Init kendo
        app = new kendo.mobile.Application($(document.body), { layout: 'main-layout', skin:'flat'});
        window.app = app;
        
        ///


    };

    function onPause() {
        console.log("pause");
        // TODO: This application has been suspended. Save application state here.
    };

    function onResume() {
        console.log("resume");
        // TODO: This application has been reactivated. Restore application state here.
    };
    
    function back() {
        console.log("back!!!!");
    };
    
})();​
```

This code create VS automatically. I just add only addEventListener("backbutton)" and function back(). 
Now, I try debug this app, and backbutton event never called when I put hardware backbutton. And no console messages. Where is my error?

**upd**: and I add in this code kendo app initialize.

**upd2** in android emulator this code work. but in wp8.1 emulator and device don't.

Comment: I am not sure of the quirks on windows phone but maybe try to catch the event on the bubbling phase. I.e. change document.addEventListener('backbutton', back.bind(this), true); to document.addEventListener('backbutton', back.bind(this), false);

Comment: Thanks for answer. I try it, but in don't help.

Comment: Try using this:
 document.addEventListener('backbutton', function (e) {
...DO WHAT YOU WANT HERE...
}, false);

Comment: Thanks for answer. Try, don't work :(

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17090346/windows-phone-8-javascript-back-button) appears to highlight a similar issue. Are you the event listener is being attached ? Also [this](http://www.risingj.com/archives/493) appears to talk more in depth about window 8 back button.

Comment: I'm not sure the event is being attached. How can I find it?

Comment: Do you see 'resume' and 'pause' events being fired in Windows Phone 8.1 by any chance?